# Unable to find specific element using Cypress xpath

Tags: cypress

In my application it requires to expand the branch.I want to write code to expand the branch

I used following xpath command but all failed
cy.xpath('//li[@rel="000003ee-1111-1111-0000-0700000000002" and @class="branch collapsed"]').click()

cy.find('[class="branch collapsed"][rel="000003ee-1111-1111-0000-0700000000002"]').click()

Comment: This is the source code when  node  is collapsed - <li class="branch collapsed" rel="000003ee-1111-1111-0000-070000000000" style="" xpath="1">

Comment: This is the source code when  node  is expanded - <li class="branch expanded" rel="000003ee-1111-1111-0000-070000000000" style="" xpath="1">

Comment: If you can share some more DOM or element info, then people will understand your issue and be more inclined to help.